# Is it possible to associate an extension one way for Windows Explorer and another way for the command line?

Tags: command-line, file-association

I have several "executable file types", like FinalBuilder scripts with an extension `.fbp8`.

I want the following scenario:

- If I type the name `test` on the command prompt, the script will be executed with the `FBCMD.exe` command line script runner
- However, if I double-click the same file in Windows Explorer, the GUI IDE will be opened up instead, to edit the file

Is this possible? If so, how do I go about setting it up?

It seems that if I change the association to be towards `FBCMD.exe`, this is also used by Windows Explorer and thus double-clicking on the file will execute it.

I have already set up `PATHEXT` like this,

```
SET PATHEXT=.FBP8;%PATHEXT%
```

and right now the registry looks like this:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
    .FBP8
        (Default)                REG_SZ    FinalBuilder8.Project

    FinalBuilder8.Project
        shell
            open
                command
                    (Default)    REG_SZ    "C:\Program Files (x86)\FinalBuilder 8\FinalBuilder8.exe" "%1"
```

*(there's some other bits and pieces in there as well for additional right-click items in Explorer, let me know if they are required)*

If I change this the command line will take notice but so will Windows Explorer. Is it possible to have my cake and eat it too?